# Using SikuliX to move a virtual machine's cursor

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, mouselistener, sikuli

In VirtualBox (a virtual machine software), you can navigate around the virtual machine with mouse capture. This means you click on the window, and your cursor freezes and a new cursor appears inside your [virtual] machine. You navigate this new mouse with your trackpad/mouse just like normal, but SikuliX (a program that moves your mouse around) doesn't do that. Every time it moves/clicks, it does so with the real mouse, not the virtual one, even though if these same actions were done by hand they would capture the mouse/enter the virtual machine. Why is this, and how can I make it so that Sikuli moves the virtual mouse? And no, I can't install Sikuli inside the virtual machine as it's Android (Sikuli's unsupported on mobile).

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/185791: "Some people succeeded in using some VNC solution.

But as I understand, Sikuli does not work in any "headless" situation."